# Magento 1.4.2.0 - Create new order - cannot choose customer group

Tags: magento, magento-1.4

Im having the exact same problem as this user:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/284012/

Although no solution was posted.

When I try and create a new order , all works fine except I cannot choose a custom group. Checking anything else in the dropdown results in the loading dialog , and it then resetting to the default value.

No errors are thrown in the logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This , it seems is related to payment gateways. Specifically in this case , SagePay. Removing the SagePay plugin solved the issue.

In 1.3 we were using a different plugin than what works in 1.4.